# Missing records when ordering rows by date

Tags: mysql

This would be my query:

`SELECT * FROM Bans ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10`

Here's how the timestamp(Date) looks: `September 01, 2012 - 10:33:13` | `May 31, 2012 - 19:28:25`, etc.. Now, my problem is, is that I have records from June, but they aren't showing.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Edit: This table should show the "Latest" 10 bans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may supose that dates are sorted in the alphabetical order, maybe you should try

```
SELECT * FROM Bans ORDER BY TO_SECONDS(Date) DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I get this: `FUNCTION MY_DB.TO_SECONDS does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

`Date` might be considered as a keyword in MySQL. Wrap it inside the backticks. Dates are not in the correct form. Use [`TO_SECONDS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds) and alter the query this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `Bans` ORDER BY TO_SECONDS(`Date`) DESC LIMIT 10
```